# How to show another html in div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one `fixed left side menu bar` with 5 menus in `layout.html` page. each `li` contains separate html file.
I am loading `.body-content` from external HTML.
My doubt is when I click on menu list, regarding content should be displayed inside of body content.But in my code its navigating to new page. I know that is because of I gave directly file path to href.

 can anyone tell me how to change Only `.body-content` data at the time of href is clicked?

layout.html

```
<ul class="nav main-menu">
  <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
    <a href="home.html" class="dropdown-toggle">                  
      <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
      <span class="hidden-xs">Dashboard</span>
    </a>                        
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
    <a href="usermanagement.html" class="dropdown-toggle">                  
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      <span class="hidden-User Management</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
  <div class="body-content">                                     
  </div>  
</div>
```

home.html

```
<h2>Sample content</h2>
<p>This HTML tutorial contains hundreds of HTML examples.

With our online HTML editor, you can edit the HTML, and click on a button to view the result.</p>
```

usermanagement.html

```
<h2>Sample content</h2>
<p>jQuery is a JavaScript Library.

jQuery greatly simplifies JavaScript programming.

jQuery is easy to learn.</p>
```

Comment: use jquery .get() to get the html from path and render in target element using .html()

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following jquery (ajax) function to load the html of another page in given div, you can also call this on page onload or any event.

```
    $(function() {
       $(".dropdown > a").click(function(e){
          $( ".body-content" ).load( "usermanagement.html", function() {
            alert( "page content has been loaded" );
          });
       });
    }
```

It seems that you are using AngularJS in your code, you can also use the ng-include to load html page content as following way,

```
<div class="body-content" ng-include="usermanagement.html"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp). Use [ajax()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) method preferably because [load()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_load.asp) is actually deprecated, and [get()/post()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) methods mentionated by the other users can be specified in `ajax()`(by default is `GET`).
You will also need [html()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp) to set the content of the `div` and [preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp) method to stops the default action of the anchor from happening:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown > a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var val = $(this).attr("href")
        $.ajax({
            url: val, 
            success: function(result){
                $(".body-content").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your answer but am getting this error `jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 Failed to load file:///D:/projects/html/Dashboard/dashboard.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: Then I tried to run my program in `analogx`.But its showing `unable to start server,check file server.log for details` error

Comment: Try in different browser, or try follow the help of next link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to get the data and [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to add it to your div.

```
$.get( "file.html", function( data ) {
  $('.body-content').html( data );
});
```

To make your menu dynamic, I suggest to bind a function to all the anchors inside `.main-menu`:

```
$(function() {
  $('.main-menu a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); /* prevent the link from opening */
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); /* get the url */
    $.get( url, function( data ) {
      $('.body-content').html( data );
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I got `$.get(...).success is not a function` error. so I have changed my code like this.......

Comment: $scope.init = function(){
                $(function() {
                    $('.main-menu a').on('click', function(e) {debugger
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                        var url = $(this).attr('href');
                        $.get( url )
                        .then(function( data ) { 
                        $('.body-content').html( data ); 
                       },
                         function(error) { 
                        $('.body-content').html( 'Error while loading the page' ); 
                        })   });
                });      }

Comment: Now am getting this error `jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 Failed to load file:///D:/projects/html/Dashboard/dashboard.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: Check the docs, https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/, `.success` is valid function. However they give another solution, so I changed my answer